# Shopify dynamic products

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Was wondering if anyone knows or have came across this shopify functionality I am looking. Basically you have images as a color option and when you select one it dynamically updates the featured image and the gallery.

Similar to this:
https://www.rugsusa.com/rugsusa/rugs/rugs-usa-shag/Natural/200SPRE14A-305.html

Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, tutorials or other off-site resources are considered '[**off-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)' for StackOverflow. Please refer to the StackOverflow help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the documentation for topics that are considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)'. You're also expected to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and showcase a **specific** problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I may rephrase your main question (Hopefully I've understood what you're after):

### In Shopify, can I automatically update the product image based on the user's option selections?

### Answer:

**Yes!**

Many (if not most/all) themes in Shopify support this natively - if variants in your products are assigned featured images through the product admin, the theme will update the main product image to that variant's featured image.

Not all themes have built-in colour swatches, but those that do should be able to replicate the style of your linked store without too much trouble.  (Different themes with swatch support have different ways of implementing those swatches - you will want to check your theme's documentation to find out how to best set up your swatches for your store)

Hope this helps!